# what is the difference between (!a==b) and (a != b) in JS?

Tags: javascript

```
if(openmenu != para){
addClass(openmenu , 'collapsed');
}
```

I am a beginner of JS, I want to add a classname to a element after a if statement. However, `if(openmenu != para)` and `if(!openmenu == para)` showed completely different result. Does anyone know why?

Comment: [Equality comparisons and sameness - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: It depends on what the values of `openmenu` and `para` are. That's fundamental information to include in the question. **If** they were both booleans, those two comparisons would have the same result. So clearly, they're not both booleans.

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements). Duplicate targets found by searching [`[js] code:"!x === y"`](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+code%3A%22%21x+%3D%3D%3D+y%22) and [`site:stackoverflow.com js "!=="`](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+%22%3D%3D!%22).

Answer (score 1):

`!openmenu == para` is parsed as `(!openmenu) == para`, so it first negates `openmenu` and then checks whether it is equal to `para`, which is most likely not what you want to do. You could write `!(openmenu == para)` which would mean the same thing as `openmenu != para`.

Answer (score 0):

`!a == b` inverts `a`'s value. For example if it's `true`, using `!` will invert it to `false`.

`if(!true == false)` equals to `if(false == false)` which results as `true`.

but `if(a != b)` compares values, lets say `a` is true and `b` is `false`, so `if(true == false)` => `false` values are not the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if `a==null` and `b==false`
so `!a = true`.

Then `!a == b` is false but `a!=b` is true.
I hope that answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing different values. When you add `!` in front it toggles the value between `true` and `false`

```js
const openmenu = 1;
const para = 2;

console.log(!openmenu) // toggles to false
console.log(!para) // toggles to false
console.log(!openmenu == para) // false == 2
console.log(openmenu != para) // 1 != 2

console.log(!"Turtle") // converts to false
```